# Creation of an Azure Media Service Job fails after deploying to server (iis8)

Tags: azure, iis-8, windows-server-2012, azure-media-services

I am having some problems with the Azure Media Service. I have successfully managed to upload a file to Azure Media Service and encoded it as mp4, but this will only work on localhost in visual studio. When I deploy the following code to a Azure Virtual Machine, Windows Datacenter 2012 edition, the file is uploaded **but the encoding job is never created**.

Any help is much appreciated!

This is the code I use to create the job:

```
                // Declare a new job.
                job= _context.Jobs.Create("New Job");

                // Get a media processor reference, and pass to it the name of the 
                // processor to use for the specific task.
                IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Windows Azure Media Encoder");

            // Create a task with the encoding details, using a string preset.
            ITask task = job.Tasks.AddNew("LSVEncodingTask_" + v.CompanyId + "_user" + v.UserId,
                processor,
                "H264 Broadband 1080p",
                TaskOptions.ProtectedConfiguration);

            // Specify the input asset to be encoded.
            task.InputAssets.Add(asset);

            // Add an output asset to contain the results of the job. 
            // This output is specified as AssetCreationOptions.None, which 
            // means the output asset is not encrypted. 
            task.OutputAssets.AddNew("output asset",
                AssetCreationOptions.None);

            // Use the following event handler to check job progress.  
            job.StateChanged += new
                EventHandler<JobStateChangedEventArgs>(StateChanged);

            // Launch the job.
            job.Submit();

            // Check job execution and wait for job to finish. 
            Task progressJobTask = job.GetExecutionProgressTask(CancellationToken.None);
```

**EDIT:**

Did some digging (logging...) and found the stack trace:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access is denied.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store.Open(OpenFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.EncryptionUtils.SaveCertificateToStore(X509Certificate2 certToStore)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.ContentKeyBaseCollection.GetCertificateForProtectionKeyId(IMediaDataServiceContext dataContext, String protectionKeyId)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.ProtectTaskConfiguration(TaskData task, X509Certificate2& certToUse, IMediaDataServiceContext dataContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.InnerSubmit(IMediaDataServiceContext dataContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.SubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.JobData.Submit()
   at Livescreen.Domain.Implementation.AzureMediaManager.CreateEncodingJob(IAsset asset, String inputMediaFilePath, String outputFolder, Int32 videoId)
```

Comment: tell us what you have tried so far to diagnose/debug the issue? There are tools like Fiddler which are great in tracing Web requests. There are things like Windows Event Log where you can look for suspicious entries, and so on. Please try first solving the problem on your own, then present here the attempted solutions and the fail codes/stack traces in order to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67216e79-c259-4685-95d0-3a09bab5c0c5/getting-systemsecuritycryptographycryptographicexception-access-is-denied-error-on?forum=wcf):

> *When running on IIS7 - you can specify to load the user profile of the App Pool. This gives you access to the per user store of the app
>   pool account.*

**Solution:**

[image: The solution]